# How to run VLC stream on Linux server using Java code?

Tags: java, linux, shell, streaming, vlc

I am trying to run vlc stream from my Java code on Debian server.
Simple commands as given in the example below works fine both from java code as well as terminal.

```
String cmd = "/Applications/ video.avi"
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But I try to run more advanced command with multiple options"

```
vlc -vvv http://umevakameran.net.umea.se/mjpg/video.mjpg --no-audio --sout '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{mime=image/jpeg},mux=mpjpeg,dst=xxxxx:25000}'
```

This is my main class:

```
NewCamera obj = new NewCamera();
...
String mobile_command = "vlc -d -vvv " + camera.getUrl() + 
" --no-audio --sout"
+ " '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:"
+ "standard{access=http{mime=image/jpeg},mux=mpjpeg,dst="
+ camera.getServerName() + ":"
+ camera.getMobilePort() + "}'";

obj.executeCommand(mobile_command);
logger.info("New mobile stream started");
```

and this is class for executing shell commands:

```
    private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        logger.info(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info(output.toString());
    return output.toString();

}
```

Process in Linux is created, but the stream is I will say "offline", because I cannot connect and get it. Executing the same command directly from command line in Linux works and creates stream.

Any ideas?

Comment: That p.waitFor() call will block. You only consume the stream *afterwards* so I don't think that's working as you expect. I would recommend you look here for a reliable solution: http://commons.apache.org/exec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use VLCJ instead of calling vlc by shell.

[http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/faq.htm](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/faq.html)l

Answer (score 0):

I changed approach:

```
vlc -d -vvv http://camera_ip/mjpg/video.mjpg --no-audio --sout '#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,venc=ffmpeg{strict=1}}:standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=server_name:port}' &
```

with this it works fine. Also I changed approach to run shell scripts. Now I use `Process Builder` instead of simple `Process`.